# Merging two Mongoose query results, without turning them into JSON

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate, mongoose-schema

I have two Mongoose model schemas setup so that the child documents reference the parent documents, as opposed to the Parent documents having an array of Children documents. (Its like this due to the 16MB size limit restriction on documents, I didnt want to limit the amount of relationships between Parent/Child docs):

```js
// Parent Model Schema
const parentSchema = new Schema({
    name: Schema.Types.String
})


// Child Model Schema
const childSchema = new Schema({
    name: Schema.Types.String,
    _partition: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Parent'
    }
})
```

I want to create a static method that I can query for a Parent document, then query for any Child documents that match the parent document, then create a new item in the parent document that will reference the Children array.

Basically if the Parent document is:

```js
{
    _id: ObjectId('56ba258a98f0767514d0ee0b'),
    name: 'Foo'
}
```

And the child documents are:

```js
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId('56b9b6a86ea3a0d012bdd062'),
        name: 'Name A',
        _partition: ObjectId('56ba258a98f0767514d0ee0b')
    },{
        _id: ObjectId('56ba7e9820accb40239baedf'),
        name: 'Name B',
        _partition: ObjectId('56ba258a98f0767514d0ee0b')
    }
]
```

Then id be looking to have something like:

```js
{
    _id: ObjectId('56ba258a98f0767514d0ee0b'),
    name: 'Foo',
    children: [
        {
            _id: ObjectId('56b9b6a86ea3a0d012bdd062'),
            name: 'Name A',
            _partition: ObjectId('56ba258a98f0767514d0ee0b')
        },{
            _id: ObjectId('56ba7e9820accb40239baedf'),
            name: 'Name B',
            _partition: ObjectId('56ba258a98f0767514d0ee0b')
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, I want them to remain Mongoose documents, so I can update the Parents and Assets if I need to.

I was able to accomplish this by using `toJSON` on the Parent, then creating a new item that would hold the Child docs, but then obviously the Parent document isn't a real document..

The error I kept getting when I tried this was that I couldnt create a new element in the Document that wasnt in the schema.

I know I could do something like create a Virtual item that would return the promise that would query the Children, but im looking to have one static method, that returns one response (meaning they dont have to handle the virtual item as a promise or callback)

Let me know if this is possible. Thanks!

Comment: Well `.toJSON()` was surely overkill as this would "stringify" and then you would need to parse the JSON back to a JavaScript object in order to manipulate. Perhaps you meant or should have used `.toObject()` instead. At any rate, you generally need that because these are not really JavaScript Objects but "mongoose documents", with just a liitle magic to make their serialized and accessed form "look like" plain objects, but they are not.

Comment: The other interesting thing is that your manipulation is the "reverse" of common populate usage. If instead your "parent" already contained an array of "child" references, then the result you want would be a very simple `.populate()` call.

Comment: The reason I decided to store it like this is because of the amount of possible children, there is no limit, and there cant be for this app. And since Mongoose documents max out at 16MB, that would be a limit. Think of the Parents/Children as DataCenters/Servers, it can be quite a large amount. And  wouldnt the `.toObject()` turn it into a JS Object, meaning I couldnt handle it like a Mongoose document? I still want to be able to execute methods and update/save the docs

Answer (score 1):

FYI, this apparently isn't possible, I've tried a few things and it doesn't seem like it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .populate() method of the schema.

```
Parent.find(query)
    .populate("children")
    .exec((err, items) => {
        if (err) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    });
```